# Which scriptures mention about Sutak dosha (various prohibitions on child birth)?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rituals, smriti

Generally there are various prohibitions when a child is born in a family. It goes upto several days like 11 days which is called Sutak period. There are also various community rules regarding no. of days.

So, I want to know which scriptures mention about Sutak dosha? Most probably it's mentioned in Smritis. What are prohibitions on it? Upto how many days does it extend ?

Also, Is Sutak dosha mentioned in Vedic sources like Samhitas, Brahmanas, Upanishads etc... ? Is it at least mentioned in Mahabharata?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## which scriptures mention about Sutak dosha?

[Manu Smriti, Chapter 5](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm) declares ten days of Sutaka (impurity) for Sapinda.

> 77. A man who hears of a (Sapinda) relative's death, or of the birth of a son after the ten days (of impurity have passed), becomes pure by bathing, dressed in his garments.

[Vishnu Smriti, Chapter 22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe07/sbe07024.htm) gives impurity period by each Varna.

> 1. The impurity of a Brâhmana caused by the birth or death of Sapindas lasts ten days.
> 2. In the case of a Kshatriya (it lasts) twelve days.
> 3. In the case of a Vaisya (it lasts) fifteen days.
> 4. In the case of a Sûdra (it lasts) a month.

[Gautama Smriti, Chapter 14](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0278.htm) agree with Vishnu Smriti. It declares:

> 14. (The rules regarding impurity caused by the death of a relative apply) to the birth (of a child) also.

And then

> 1. The Sapindas become impure by the death (of a relative) during ten (days and) nights, except those who officiate as priests, who have performed the Dîkshanîyeshti (or initiatory ceremony of a Srauta sacrifice), and those who are students.
> 2. (The impurity) of a Kshatriya lasts for eleven (days and) nights,
> 3. (That) of a Vaisya twelve (days and) nights,
> 4. (Or), according to some, half a month,
> 5. (And that) of a Sûdra a whole month

[Vashishtha Smriti, Chapter 4](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe14/sbe1407.htm) also declares the same.

> 26. A Brâhmana is freed from impurity (caused by a death or a birth) after ten days,
> 27. A Kshatriya after fifteen days,
> 28. A Vaisya after twenty days,
> 29. A Sûdra after a month.

[Parashara Smriti, Chapter 3](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt) allow Brahmana to be pure after three days.

> 1. Now I shall speak of the term of impurity resulting 
>      on the occurrence of a birth, or a death. Brahmans in 
>      three days become pure again, when a relative has died, or 
>      has been born.
> 2. A Kshatriya recovers purity in twelve days ; a Vaisya, when fifteen days have passed ; a Shoodra, after the lapse of a 
>      month ; this is conformable to what Parasara has said.

## What are prohibitions on it?

[Vishnu Smriti, Chapter 22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe07/sbe07024.htm) gives following prohibitions:

> 6. During the period of impurity oblations (to the Visvedevâs), gifts and receiving of alms, and study have to be interrupted.

Other prohibitions are given in [Rickross's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/which-scriptures-mention-about-sutak-dosha-various-prohibitions-on-child-birth/21389#21389).

Comment: Can you also include prohibitions in Sutak period?...

Answer (score 8):

Here is a **partial answer**.

> Upto how many days does it extend ?

The number of days for which the impurity is extended remains the same for both Mritaka (death) and Sutaka (birth).

> After a death, a ten-day period of impurity is enjoined on those
>   belonging to the same ancestry (the verse is repeated in Apasthambha).
>
> 17 Relatives up to the sixth degree, it is said, fall under the
>   category of common ancestry, 18and in the case of married women, up to
>   the second degree. Others should perform the funerary rites of
>   married women; and such women should perform them for those people.
>   20 **The very same rule regarding impurity applies also to a birth for
>   those who desire perfect purity.**
>
> 21 alternatively, it applies only to the mother and the father, or,
>   according to some, only to the mother, because the birth results from
>   her.
>
> 23 Now, they also quote: At a birth there is no period of impurity for
>   the man, unless he comes into contact with her.
>
> **A Brahmin becomes pure after ten days, a Ksatriya after fifteen days,
>   a Vais´ya after twenty days, and a Sudra after a month.**
>
> **Vashistha Dharma Sutras 4.17-38**

.................

> What are prohibitions on it?

Most of the Dvijakarmas are to be abandoned except Sandhya-rites which can still be continued with slight variations (like without reciting mantras loudly, without pranayama and reciting sankalpam):

> A Vipra, [on the occasion of a birth or death] **should refrain**, for ten
>   days, from making gifts or studying the Veda's. A Kshatriya is
>   purified in twelve days ; a Vais'ya in fifteen days ; and a S'udra in
>   a month. Such is the deliverance of Samvarta.
>
> A twice-born person should, daily and duly, perform- the five
>   sacrifices. A Vipra, seeking his well-being, should, under no
>   circumstances, abandon them. **One should, [however,] always abandon
>   them [in an impurity consequent] on birth and death.**
>
> **Samvarta Smriti**

However one should also note the following verse:

> There is no sin, if any intervening impurity, consequent on a birth or
>   death, takes place, in the celebration of a marriage, festivity, or a
>   sacrifice, **determined upon before**. So Atri has said.
>
> **Atri Smriti**

As regards proving the fact that Sandhya-Rites can still be performed during these Asuchi days, we can quote from the book [Dharma Bindu](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjfoo2OnN7WAhVGqo8KHV_7DjIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kamakoti.org%2Fkamakoti%2Farticles%2FDharma%2520Bindu.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0eZP6o3ks_x7jsfchJG4X7):

> Sutake mritakechaiva Sandhyaakarma samaacharet 
>  Manasocchhaarayet
>   mantraan praanaayaamaadrute |
>
> **Sandhyopaasana needs to be performed both during ‘Jaataashoucha’or
>   ‘Mritaashoucha’ or Ashuddhi on account of births or deaths, by maanaso
>   cchaarana or recitation of mantras mentally without resorting to pranaayama, confirms Pulastya Maharshi.**
>
> Vyaasa too states: Prakshipet sutaket arghyam Gayatreem
>   samuccharan,
>  Datvaa pradakshi - nam kuryaat Suryam dhyaayet
>   dvijottaamah,
>  Dasha krutastu Gayatreem manasaiva Shuchih smaret
>
> During Jaataashoucha too, a Dvija could recite Gayatri and perform by
>   way of Surya dhyaana pradakshinas. **During the ten days of Ashuchi,
>   Gayatri should be recited by one’s own mind.**

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer!... (but I have accepted another answer as I can't accept two answers )

Comment: @Tezz haha ..that's perfectly ok. :)

Comment: @Rickross is ekadashi prohibited during sutak period?

Comment: Yes in general all fasts are prohibited during sutak be it Ekadashi or Shiva ratri @Harsh

Comment: @Rickross thanks

Comment: No problem @Harsh

Comment: Can we recite stotras in sutak period? Or like sing any song as in general or nama samkirtana etc.? Do scriptures say anything about it?

Comment: No it should not be recited because stotras are meant to be recited only loudly ..  During Sutak only recitation in mind is allowed ... so doing mantra japa silently is allowed @LSSJBroly

Comment: Okay thanks . .. .

Answer (score 0):

Regard Sutak as a health advisement recommending Quarantine and rest.

For Death prevent infections and also give time for psychological impact of bereavement. Longer Quarantine period for those who will interact with greater volume of people. Hence longest Quarantine for Service providers “Sudra” varna.

For Birth, polite way for people to be asked to stay away and protect baby from infection and give new mother resting time
After Birth. Believe thats the core question being asked.

Comment: Please follow answering guidelines. This is not an answer; delete this please if you do not have scriptural references.

Comment: This is not a proper answer.