# Why we don't do any puja when someone dies?

Tags: scripture, rituals, worship, death

I have heard that whenever someone dies, their relatives dont do any puja till 11th or 13th day, not sure about time. Is it mentioned in shastras?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21388/8735

Comment: @Ketan yes and thanks for that.

Comment: @Rudra u must be seeing an option to close this Question as duplicate..

Comment: @YDS yeah. Did it